# I need to count the number of times a substring occurs in a file using scanner and JFIleChooser

Tags: java, substring, java.util.scanner, jfilechooser

I am trying to learn Java and I want to know how I can count the number of times a substring occurs in a chosen text file and have it output to the console. For example say I used `JFileChooser` to grab a text file from my computer and I wanted to know how many times the substring "if" or "ot" occurred in the file. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class FileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(/* How do I get the file? */);
        { // file read
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                count++;
                in.next();
            }
            System.out.println("The word count is " + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to stackover flow,how do i post the code so its not all jumbled up?

Comment: Indent the first line 4 spaces and use shift+enter when you need a new line.

Comment: oh my god haha I've never used this before but its not working. I'm copying it straight from eclipse. I indented the first line 4 spaces

Comment: You can edit your question. Please add the code to the question as described by @TheHeadRush.

Comment: Needs to go in your main post, not a comment.

Comment: ok ok I got it, sorry. It's still not formatted correctly but I hope you can figure it out

Comment: It's ok I got you broski.  You need to use the code tag btw.

Comment: forgive me, like I said I'm trying to learn the language and I have no prior coding experience

Comment: I didn't know that you guys could make editing suggestions. Sorry. But I approved an edit that is more clear than my original post

Comment: You do not need to be sorry. We all had to learn this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to actually display the open dialog. You can do this with the method `showOpenDialog`. Afterwards, you want to get the selected file from the chooser by calling `chooser.getSelectedFile()`. This file is stored in the variable `file`.

Now, you need to open the file for reading. In Java you do this with a `FileInputStream`. You can pass this to the constructor of the class `Scanner`, together with the character encoding how you expect the file to be encoded.

Now, you have the scanner initialized. To ensure, that all resources are released after you are done, you can use Java's try-with-resource statement, which is of the form

```
try (/* open resource */) {/* use resource */}
```

In this case, the scanner is the resource which should be closed. When the scanner is closed, the file is closed.

Then, you only want to count the occurrences of the words "if" and "ot". To do this, you first read the word. Afterwards, check whether it is equal to one of the expected words. If it is, you increase the counter. Please note, that in Java you cannot compare Strings using the `==` operator.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class FileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8")) {
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String token = in.next();
                if (token.equals("if") || token.equals("ot")) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The word count is " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: UTF-8 is the character encoding of the file. You should always specify the character encoding when working with files. This is not limited to Java. There are many other character encodings. If you use the wrong to read or write a file, you will probably end up with a broken text in the file of in your program. I used UTF-8, since it is pretty much the standard file encoding. However, you should always make sure to use the correct encoding.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, you can accept and upvote it.

Comment: Oh ok. Well thanks again man! I'm going to be spending quite a bit of time on here

Comment: I tried to upvote it but it said something about needing 15 reputation?

Comment: You are welcome ... Ah, that is right. You can do various things on StackOverflow to earn reputation. After you earned a specific amount of reputation, you get more privileges. If you did not yet do it, you might be interested to [visit the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling streams with files you can simply use Apache's StringUtils & FileUtils to count your matching words as like follows,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class FileReader 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try
        {
            count = StringUtils.countMatches(FileUtils.readFileToString(file),"Search_String or Search_Character");
            count += StringUtils.countMatches(FileUtils.readFileToString(file),"Search_String or Search_Character");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error :" + e);
        }
        System.out.println("The word count is " + count);
    }
}
```

You can try like this also.